# How to write a Stored procedure to insert the data in table by reading the xml file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write the stored procedure for inserting the column values in to the tables Employee, & Department.which are already created And the Xml file contains the following data
which should be updated.

```
<RECORD>
    <Employee ID="1966"  EmpName="prod" Joined="1.2" > </Employee>
    <Department DepID="1977" DepName="dep"  Dephead="ok" > </Department>
</RECORD>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good linke that shows you how to use the `OPENXML` and `OPENROWSET` functions within SQL

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/